# Entity Framework C# - Cloning object with children with many-to-many relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, clone

Using EF and C#, I'm trying to make a clone of an entity which has a lot of related records. I want to clone the related records as well. The top level object is a `Bid`.

```
    class Bid 
    {
          Collection<ItemGroup> ItemGroups {get;set;}
          Collection<Evaluator> Evaluators {get;set;}
    }
```

Children being `ItemGroups` and `Evaluators`. They are many-to-many.

```
class ItemGroup
{
     Collection<Evaluator> Evaluators {get;set;}
}

Class Evaluator
{
     Collection<ItemGroup> ItemGroups {get;set;}
}
```

I clone the `Bid`, and all of it's children, by querying the database

```
Bid bid = dbContext.Bids.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault()
                   .Include(b => b.ItemGroups)
                   .Include(b => b.ItemGroups.Select(e => e.Evaluators))
```

and adding the `Bid` back in with

```
database.Bids.Add(bid);
database.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is the many-to-many relationship between `Evaluators` and `ItemGroups`. Because their collections reference eachother, when you add the `Bid` back in, it DUPLICATES the records.

So, before clone, I have a Bid:

```
Original Bid -
Number of ItemGroups = 3
Number of Evaluators = 2
```

and, after clone, I have a new Bid, with:

```
New Bid -
Number of ItemGroups = 3
Number of Evaluators = 6
```

Which is obviously incorrect. How do I clone this relationship without having EF add duplicates?

Is the problem my original query? I've tried all sorts of options, using `.Include()s` that trace from `Bid -> Evaluators -> Item Groups`, or simply just go `Bid -> Evaluator` and `Bid -> ItemGroup`, but nothing seems to get me quite what I want. Any and all help is greatly appreciated, and please just let me know if I can offer some clarifications. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have better luck fetching the entity with tracking enabled and than changing the entity state to added before saving the changes.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

I don't think this will lead to duplicating the ItemGroups and Elevators in your example but I haven't tested this.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not entirely sure that's the way I want to go though, it leads to some other unexpected behavior when cloning entities farther down the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's my super janky solution until someone can tell me a better way to do it. Basically, I leave out the many-to-many relationships in my query `Include()s`, querying for `bid.ItemGroups`, and `bid.Evaluators` only.

I add those as normal, which gives me a `Bid` with the appropriate number of item groups, and 0 evaluators, as the ItemGroup -> Evaluator relationships weren't established because i did not query for them.

Then, after calling `database.Bids.Add(bid)`, I re-query for the original bid and it's Evaluator/ItemGroup relationships, and manually hook up all of the Evaluator/ItemGroup references using names/id's/whatever identifiers are available.

```
List<Evaluator> originalEvals = db.Bids.Where(b => b.Id == entityId)
                .Select(b => b.Evaluators)
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .ToList();
            foreach(Evaluator origEval in originalEvals)
            {
                db.Entry(origEval).Reference(e => e.ClientUser).Load();
                db.Entry(origEval).Collection(e => e.ItemGroups).Load();
            }

            foreach (Evaluator newEval in bid.Evaluators)
            {
                Evaluator originalEval = originalEvals.Where(e => e.ClientUserId == newEval.ClientUserId).FirstOrDefault();

                foreach (ItemGroup ig in originalEval.ItemGroups)
                {
                    newEval.ItemGroups.Add(bid.ItemGroups.Where(g => g.Name == ig.Name).FirstOrDefault());
                }
            }
```

Shitty, but it works.